# JQuery not recognizing click on table row

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using JQuery template for the data for my table... and the CSS recognizes the table rows inside the query template script and styles them how I want... but for some reason I can't call a $().click on those same rows using the same identifier. Here's the table code:

```
<script id="donorTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<tr id="indexTR">
    <td>${Person.LastName}, ${Person.FirstName}</td>
    <td>${Address.Address1}</td>
    <td>${PhoneContact.PhoneNumber}</td>
    <td>${EmailContact.EmailContactx}</td>
    <td>${Company.CompanyName}</td>
    <td><a href="/Donation/Index?id=${Person.PersonID}">Add Donation</a></td>
    <td> <a href="/Person/Edit?id=${Person.PersonID}">Edit</a> &nbsp; <a href="/Person/Delete?    
id=${Person.PersonID}">Delete</a> &nbsp;
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="${Person.PersonID}"/>
    </td> 
</tr>
</script>

<div id="searchresults">
<table id="donor-list">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th id="f" width="150">Name: </th>
    <th width="180">Address: </th>
    <th width="85">Phone: </th>
    <th width="150">Email: </th>
    <th width="100">Company: </th>
    <th width="100"></th>
    <th id="l" width="100"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tableBody">

</tbody>
</table>
```

And the JQuery....

```
$("#donorSearch").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.getJSON(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), function (data) {
            $("#tableBody #indexTR").remove();
            $("#donorTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#tableBody");
        });
    });
```

That's all dandy... but this doesn't work:

```
$("#indexTR").click(function () {
       alert('test');
    });
```

This is what I'm trying to do on a TR click:

```
var val = $("#hiddenField").val();
var personID = parseInt(val);
location.href = "/Person/Details?id=" + personID;
```

which worked before until I switched over to the JQuery template. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Wait... Do you have multiple elements with the same `indexTR` id?

Comment: I suppose... since I'm appending to the table that row every time with different data... but before I had the same table row inside a @foreach using the model instead, not JQuery template and the click worked for each row...

Comment: So you got **invalid HTML** change from id to class! and I think my answer should help you.

Comment: tried pointing it to the class instead... that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: That's phase one, combine it with my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<tr id= "#indexTR">` doesn't exist in the DOM when it was ready so using delegate event should do the trick:

```
$('#donor-list').on('click', '#indexTR', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

**For jQuery 1.5:**

```
$('#donor-list').delegate('#indexTR', 'click', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

**Or attach the callback on every new creation of a row.**

```
$.getJSON(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), function (data) {
        $("#tableBody #indexTR").remove();
        $("#donorTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#tableBody");
        // Now attach the event:
        $("#indexTR").click(function () {
           alert('test');
        });
    });
```

And you got the problem with multiple elements with the same `id`. as discussed in the comments of your question.

Comment: The alert works (thank you!)... but this still doesn't work  $('#donor-list').delegate('#indexTR', 'click', function () {
            var val = $("#hiddenField").val();
            var personID = parseInt(val);
            location.href = "/Person/Details?id=" + personID;
        });

Comment: it isn't finding the hidden field in each row?

Comment: well... I shouldn't say it doesn't work... but it always redirects to the same page no matter which row I click on..

Comment: @redBarron. Of course it does, you use `id` selector, which means it will grab the first element, you got invalid markup there too!

Comment: @redBarron. Anyway it can be fixed like this: `$('#hiddenField', this).val()`. But you still have invalid markup.

Comment: I'm pretty new to JQuery... this has helped me to understand it more. Thanks again.

Comment: @redBarron. No prob, Good luck with the new privilege, this question gave you 12 points, you can upvote now, cheers!